# Menu Not Visible in Mobile browsers desktop site view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I used Bootstrap for design and used   tag for menu, i made two menus for different size devices(lg and xs), all working fine as per screen size devices but nothing visible in Mobile Browsers desktop site option. Please Help.

**Here is the header codes:**

```
<header id="mad-header" class="mad-header header-3">
      <div class="mad-pre-header">
        <div class="container extra-width">
          <div class="mad-header-items hide-mobile">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
              <a href="#" class="mad-link mad-logo"><img src="public/User/images/logo2.png" alt="" width="75"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 hide-mobile">
              <div class="mad-quick-links">
                <a href="#" class="mad-link blink" target="_blank">COVID-19</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="#" class="mad-link">MEDICINES</a> <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="#" class="mad-link">LAB TESTS</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="#" class="mad-link">ASK DOCTOR</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="#" class="mad-link">AYURVEDA</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 second-menu">
              <div class="mad-quick-links">
                <a href="#" class="mad-link">Login</a> <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="#" class="mad-link">Sign Up</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                <a href="#" class="mad-link">Offers</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="hide-desktop show-mobile mob-nav">
                <div class="row text-center topmenu">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 logo-mob">
                        <div class="mobile-logo text-left">
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link mad-logo"><img src="public/User/images/logo2.png" alt="" width="75"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 second-menu">
                        <div class="mad-quick-links">
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link blink" target="_blank">COVID-19</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link">MEDICINES</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link">LAB TESTS</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link">ASK DOCTOR</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link">AYURVEDA</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mainmenu text-right">
                    <div class="col-xs-5 logo-mob" style="width:36%">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 none-mob">
                        <div class="mad-quick-links">
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link">Login</a> <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link">Sign Up</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                            <a href="#" class="mad-link">Offers</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 menu-mob">
                        <nav class="mad-navigation-container text-left d-block d-sm-none show-mobile">
                            <ul class="mad-navigation mad-navigation--vertical-sm">
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="mad-link blink" target="_blank">COVID-19</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="mad-link">MEDICINES</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="mad-link">LAB TESTS</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="mad-link">ASK DOCTOR</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="mad-link">AYURVEDA</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

I used "hide-mobile" and "hide-desktop" class to display header in large screen and small scree devices as well.

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use bootstrap classes (`.d-{breakpoint}-{value} for sm, md, lg, and xl.`) to do this :

```
<!-- For your mobile section : -->
<div class="mad-header-items hide-mobile d-none d-sm-block">
<!-- For your desktop section : -->
<div class="hide-desktop show-mobile mob-nav d-block d-sm-none">
```

- You can find more information on [Bootstrap Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#how-it-works).
- All possibilities are listed [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#hiding-elements).
- And all breakpoints are listed [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints).

Comment: And if you want to use Bootstrap 5, the classes are the same, but you can find the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/).